# When Installing chainrings which are pinned, how should I orient the chain drop prevention pin?

Tags: maintenance, chainring, drivetrain, installation

I'm setting up a double crankset with a new front chainring which is ramped and pinned.  How should I orient the outer front chainring with respect to the chain drop prevention pin?  Should this line up with the crank arm, opposite the crank arm, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pin should line up with the inside of the crankarm.

Comment: Yep, the purpose of the pin is to prevent the chain from becoming wedged between the ring and the crank arm.